# Wowza convert Flv files to mp4

Tags: wowza

I have some legacy code that need to be configured on a new server. The server is a Wowza Media server 3.1. I have installed it and moved all application data.

The use for it is to record web camera videos from web and then be able to play them back.

I have already got it working to record video on the webpage and an .fla file is created correctly on the server.

But the playback doesn't work because there is no mp4 file.

What I have figured out is that there are two applications in Wowza application folder
AppRecordVideo and AppVod

These folder also resides in the content folder. On the previous server there were a mp4 file for each Flv file. But on the new server only the .flv file is created. Nothing has changed in the web application so I guess that there is something that should run on the server that converts the .flv file to mp4 and place it it the right content folder.

The flv file is streamable but I want to stream mp4 instead.

Any Idea on what is failing?

Answer (score 1):

First of all; I highly recommend to update your server to Wowza 4. Wowza 3.x is rather old by now and Wowza 4 has a web-interface that makes it easier to understand the configuration and working of your server.

To play video files via a Wowza server; you must place them in the designated content folder. By default this is the subfolder /content/ in your Wowza installation folder, but the exact path is defined in the Application.xml for the specific application. So if you have an application called "AppVod", then navigate to /conf/AppVod and read the Application.xml there, specifically the Root/Application/Streams/StorageDir value.

If you want to convert FLV files to MP4, the simplest solution is to use a tool like ffmpeg. With the latest version of ffmpeg you can do something like

```
ffmpeg -i myfile.flv -c copy myfile.mp4
```

This assumes that the video format in your FLV file is H.264 and the audio format is AAC. If not, you must do so-called "transcoding", e.g.

```
ffmpeg -i myfile.flv -c:v libx264 -c:a libfdk_aac -b:v 1000000 -b:a 128000 myfile.mp4
```

That will give you a 1Mbps video and 128Kbps audio. Of course there are lots of other ffmpeg options - feel free to Google for them or read it all on https://ffmpeg.org/documentation.html, and I bet there are many useful ffmpeg questions here on SO too.

Place the MP4 in the /content folder and then try to play e.g. with ffplay or VLC (the latter can also be played with HTML5-based players like https://hls-js.netlify.com/demo:

```
rtmp://your-server-ip/AppVod/myfile.mp4
http://your-server-ip:1935/AppVod/myfile.mp4/playlist.m3u8
```

Comment: Where do I place the ffmpeg command to run after the flv file is created?